# How can I have two HTML elements take 50% of the width each, and three take up 33% each?

Tags: css

I have three buttons which I want to each take up the same width, and combined to take up the entire width of their containing div. Sometimes one of the buttons will be hidden, and I want the other two buttons to still take up the entire width of their container and each have the same width.

I *could* run some javascript that changes their width back and forth between 50% and 33.3% when the third button is show and hidden, but I'd rather do it in pure CSS.

How can I style these buttons (and their container) so that they always take up 100% of the width, and are each the same width, no matter how many or how few of them are visible?

What I have so far:

```
<div class="btn-group" style="width: 100%;">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default" type="button" onclick="fail();" style="width: 33.3%;">FAIL</button>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default" type="button" onclick="retry();" style="width: 33.3%;">RETRY</button>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button" onclick="pass();" style="width: 33.3%;">PASS</button>
</div>
```

Comment: use `display: flex` with `flex-grow: 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `flex` on the parent and use `flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 0;` (or `flex: 1 0 0;` for short) on the children so they always occupy all of the space of the parent evenly.

```js
$('#button').on('click',function() {
  $('#foo').toggleClass('hide');
})
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.flex > button {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  background: #eee;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">click</button>

<div class="btn-group flex" style="width: 100%;">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default" type="button" onclick="fail();" style="width: 33.3%;" id="foo">FAIL</button>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default" type="button" onclick="retry();" style="width: 33.3%;">RETRY</button>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button" onclick="pass();" style="width: 33.3%;">PASS</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is helpful for these things.  Just add a `display:flex` to the parent container, and a `flex-grow:1` to the buttons.

```css
.btn-group {
  display:flex;
}
button {
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
</div>
```